# Is $\mathbb{Z}[x,y,z]$ an $\mathbb{N}$-graded ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, graded-rings

I know that my question seems to be obvious, but I really need the answer

Let $\mathbb{Z}[x, y, z]$ be a polynomial ring.  I know that it is a $\mathbb{Z}$-graded ring, but is it not in fact $\mathbb{N}$-graded?  I don't see why it is not $\mathbb{N}$-graded if we consider the degrees of polynomials.  But when I tried to use Nakayama's Lemma (the graded version), my professor told me that we cannot use it for any polynomial ring with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the degree of a polynomial is always nonnegative. What makes you think this ring is not $\mathbb{N}$-graded?

Comment: It would be helpful if you would explain why you think it is an $\mathbb{N}$-graded ring.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi When I tried to use Nakayama's Lemma (graded version), my professor told me that we cannot use it for any polynomial ring with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Well I'm not an expert in ring theory, but the fact that the grading is with $\mathbb{Z}$ and the fact that the coefficients are $\mathbb{Z}$ are quite unrelated. $\mathbb{R}[x,y,z]$ is $\mathbb{Z}$-graded too (and even $\mathbb{N}$-graded).

Comment: @Hrodelbert It is $\mathbb{N}$-graded because we don't have nonnegative degrees and so $\mathbb{Z}[x, y, z]_r = 0$ for $r \leq 0$.

Comment: Just to add a possible misinterpretation of what your professor may have said: You can't apply Nakayama's lemma to a $\mathbb{Z}$ graded ring which has negative degree terms - at least I don't think so. I don't really know what the analogue of the "maximal homogeneous ideal" would be in, for example, $k[x,x^{-1}]$. Presumably there isn't a good analogue...

Answer (score 4):

You're totally right that it is $\mathbb{N}$-graded, and that you can use the graded Nakayama lemma over this ring.  After all, the degree of any polynomial is nonnegative, regardless of what coefficients you're using.  Either your professor made a mistake or you misunderstood what they were trying to say.

Answer (score 2):

A $G$-grading (or: $G$-gradation) in a graded object (a $G$-graded, $k$-algebra $R$ or a  $G$-graded,  left $R$-module, $_{R}M$ with $k$ a field or a commutative ring) is usually defined with respect to a group $G$ and it can be shown that for any group $G$, a $G$-grading is the same thing as a (co)action of  $(kG)^{*}$ (where $(kG)^{*}$ is the dual hopf algebra of the group hopf algebra $kG$) on the respective object.

A consequence of the above, is that if $G$ is a finite abelian group, in which case $kG\cong (kG)^{*}$ as hopf algebras (i.e. self-dual), then  each $G$-grading is equivalent to a specific action of $G$ on the respecting object. $\mathbb{N}$ is not a group and I guess this is why it is custom to speak about a $\mathbb{Z}$-graded object but not an $\mathbb{N}$-graded object.

More generally, gradations can also be defined with respect to some monoid or semi-group, which means that it is legitimate to view your polynomial ring either as $\mathbb{Z}$-graded or $\mathbb{N}$-graded. So, the graded version of Nakayama's Lemma applies.  However, in the literature it is the group-grading case which is mostly explored and which presents a wealth of behaviours (in the sense that it can provide deep insights into the structure of the graded ring, algebra or module).

Comment: What is $k$ supposed to be in your answer?

Comment: In the above description, $k$ is a field but more generally, it can also be a commutative ring

Comment: Note that the last paragraph does not change that much in the present case, as the monoid is commutative and cancellative, so it embeds into a group, and we may as well consider the algebra graded by this group instead (though we would obviously then have to extend the category of graded modules to allow these new gradings, but this gives much nicer behaved category anyway).

Comment: yes you are right. and generally, if we extend the category of modules to the group graded case, for the finite abelian case, then we can take advantage of the possible bicharacters of the group, to define R-matrices and quasitriangular structures in $kG$, leading thus to braided monoidal categories of modules.